# Reversal of integers by encoding and decoding

Tags: java, math, logic

I have to reverse a set of 32 numbers which are in the range 0-255. I have to encode it into a float value. While decoding i will have the last integer and the float value. From these values I have to reverse the numbers. I have tried a bit but i am not getting it.

```
import java.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Reverse {
    public static void main(String ab[]) {
       int input[] = new int[32];
       double prev = 0, f;
        int n;
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("enter the no. of inputs");
        n = sc.nextInt();
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            input[i] = sc.nextInt();
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            if (j == 0) {
                prev = input[j];
            } else {
                f = 1 / prev;
                f += input[j];
                prev = f;
            }
        }
        int count = 0;
        double temp;
        while (count < n) {
            count++;
            System.out.println(Math.round(prev));
            prev -= Math.floor(prev);
            temp = 1 / prev;
            prev = temp;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your task is still unclear. What do you need to encode into a float value?

Comment: Those 32 numbers.

Comment: You can't fit 32 bytes into a float. Floats are 32 bits.

Comment: Yes. I have to convert those integers into a single float value ie, 32 bits. if my input is- 255 87 56 43 21 i have to get the output - 21 43 56 87 255

Comment: If you have 32 values from `0-255` that means you've got 32 bytes of information. You do know the difference between bits and bytes? You can't fit them in a float or a double without losing information.

Comment: You could look at something like [Godel numbering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%C3%B6del_numbering), but I don't know if a double is going to be big enough.

Comment: Yes I do. The thing is I have to use some mathematical functions and convert them into a single float(or double) value. And also I have to find a formula by using that float value and the last integer to get all those integers in a reversal order. And i'm not getting it